# NodeJS 0.10. No 'data' event emitted on net.Socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, eventemitter

I have code to log every connection to my HTTP-server on a socket level and also log any incoming data.

This code was originally written for NodeJS 0.8 and works good there.

No my project is migrated to 0.10.24 and socket logging code stopped working.

Here is my code:

```
var netLogStream = fs.createWriteStream('net.log');

(function(f) {
    net.Server.prototype.listen = function(port) {
        var rv = f.apply(this, arguments); // (1)
        rv.on('connection', function(socket) { // (2)
            socket.on('data', function(data) {
                data.toString().split('\n').forEach(function(line) { // (3)
                    netLogStream.write('... some logging here ... ' + line);
                });
            });
        });
        return rv;
    };
})(net.Server.prototype.listen);
```

On 0.10 I can get to `(1)` and get `Socket` instance on `(2)` but I never get to `(3)`. Same time my whole application works fine without any issues.

**ADD**: My server is created with Express@3.4.x

Comment: You're not listening for the 'listen' event (pun not intended).

Comment: @Brandon why I should to?

Comment: Note that the underlying streaming changed a LOT from 0.8->0.10.  See: http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/  I can't quite tell yet if you need an additional handler vs. what you have now but I'd pore that over.

Comment: @Joe `rv` is `return value`. I was sure this is a `net.Server` (`this`), but now can't find any proof in docs...

Comment: It actually seems to work okay for me in 0.10.24 (although I'm testing by writing to stdout instead of a file, perhaps there's some buffering going on?). How are you testing if it's working or not? ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/e47a46bfd5c6999c7c98)).

Comment: @robertklep I'm adding a `console.log(...)` lines just above points `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)` and can't see any hits on `(3)` but can see `(1)` and `(2)`. Also `net.log` stream is created ok, I can see an empty file on disk.

Comment: @Olegas check out the gist I mentioned, see if that works. It does for me.

Comment: @robertklep Yes, your Gist is working fine for me... But my app won't. My app's server is created using Express framework. Maybe it is somehow related to Express vs NodeJS 0.10...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the results are different between node v0.8 and v0.10, but if I had to guess, I'd be looking at the return value of `net.Server.prototype.listen`.

According to the [documentation](http://www.nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback), this is an asynchronous method which emits the 'listen' event and invokes its callback when the listening is bound.  You're not looking for that event, but rather, capturing the return value of listen, which for an async function, may not be well-defined.  It's obviously not `null` or `undefined` since you don't get a runtime error, but the return value may not be the same between v0.8 and v0.10.

I honestly don't know for sure because I don't do low-level socket coding, but I have 2 suggestions to try:

1. Since the `connection` event is emitted from the `Server` object, perhaps you need `this.on` instead of `rv.on`.
2. Setup the `connection` event listener before you invoke `listen` just to minimize risk of race conditions.

Try this and see what happens:

```
var netLogStream = fs.createWriteStream('net.log');

(function(f) {
    net.Server.prototype.listen = function(port) {
        this.on('connection', function(socket) { // (2)
            socket.on('data', function(data) {
                data.toString().split('\n').forEach(function(line) { // (3)
                    netLogStream.write('... some logging here ... ' + line);
                });
            });
        });
        return f.apply(this, arguments); // (1)
    };
})(net.Server.prototype.listen);
```